# How do I execute my script by just typing its name?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, path

I have a script in `/home/username/scripts` and I would like to execute it by just typing its name.

I know I could do '`export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/scripts`' but I would like to have the same effect without having to export the path each time.  For instance, if another user was to have a copy of the script they could just type "scriptname.sh" instead of "./scriptname.sh".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either put it in one of the existing directories in `$PATH`, or define an alias that points to the appropriate path.

```
cp scriptname.sh /usr/local/bin
```

...

```
alias scriptname.sh=/home/username/scripts/scriptname.sh
```

The last could be done in every users `~/.bashrc` (for the users who need it). Alternatively you could add the `PATH` to the user's `~/.bash_profile`. Possibly changing the default `~/.bash_profile` in `/etc/skel` so new users get this automatically.

If the script should be available for all users, coping it to a system wide `PATH`, as mentioned above, is the best option.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to leave your script in your home (/home/username/somewhere) with proper permissions and put a symlink to /usr/local/bin as suggested. This way you will hopefully not forget to backup the script as you will usually backup your home folder.